# When to resolve into partial fractions for applying Cauchy's integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula, analytic-functions

Suppose I have to calculate $\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$ around a curve in which both $a$ and $b$ lie inside.

Should I apply Residue theorem like this:

Residue at $a$= $\frac{f(a)}{a-b}$

Residue at $b$= $\frac{f(b)}{b-a}$

Then I use the Residue theorem 2pi*(sum of residues)

OR

Should I solve it by partial fractions?

Are both valid?

My confusion with the first method is that the numerator of $\int \frac{f(z)/(z-a)}{(z-b)}$, i.e. $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ is not analytic, because $a$ also lies inside the curve. Aren't we allowed to use Cauchy's integral formula only when the numerator is analytic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both valid. If you apply the residue theorem, you'll get that the integral is equal to$$2\pi i\left(\frac{f(a)}{a-b}+\frac{f(b)}{b-a}\right)=2\pi i\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$and if you apply partial fractions together with Cauchy's integral theorem, you'll get\begin{align}\oint\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}\,\mathrm dz&=\oint\frac{f(z)}{(b-a)(z-b)}+\frac{f(z)}{(a-b)(z-a)}\,\mathrm dz\\&=\frac1{b-a}\left(\oint\frac{f(z)}{z-b}\,\mathrm dz-\oint\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,\mathrm dz\right)\\&=2\pi i\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.\end{align}

Comment: But then why are we allowed to use Cauchy's integral formula only when the numerator is analytic? Isn't integral formula just a special case of Residue theorem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Cauchy's integral formula states that if $f$ is analytic, then $\oint\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi if(a)$. Isn't that what I've used (twice) in my last equality? Which hypothesis do you claim that do not hold when I applied it? And, yes, Cauchy's integral formulais a (very) special case of the residue theorem.